# Help installing vmg magnifier program

Tags: installation, dependencies

I'm trying to install Virtual Magnifying Glass  http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/  as it's the only program I can find that has a magnifier that follows the mouse with the actual magnification shown around the cursor itself.  I haven't installed many programs, but have never had issues before, so any help is appreciated.

After installing, I try to run the program and get

vmg: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When I use ldd to check dependencies, I get.

chris@Buntzen:/usr/bin$ ldd vmg

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76fe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76c8000)
libX11.so.6 => not found
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => not found
libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => not found
libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found
libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
libcairo.so.2 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf76c1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf751a000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76ff000)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, the amd64 version.

Getting this installed would help me a lot.  Any assistance is appreciated.
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install the 32bit versions of the libraries.